# Fancy indexing with assignment for numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2 dimensional numpy array:

```
A = np.zeros(16).reshape(4,4)
```

I want the `(1, 1), (1,3), (3,1)`, and `(3,3)` cells to take a value of 1.

```
A[[1,3], [1:3]] = 1
```

Only assigns 1 to `(1,1)` and `(3,3)`.

```
A[[1,3], :][:, [1, 3]] = 1
```

Does not work because it make a copy of the data not a view. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, when you use arrays to index another array this way, `numpy` expects each array `R`, `C`, and so on, to have the same shape. So for example, suppose you want to extract the nonzero values from this array:

```
>>> a
array([[1, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

You would create an array of row indices `R`:

```
>>> R
array([[0, 2],
       [0, 2]])
```

And an array of column indices `C`:

```
>>> C
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1]])
```

And pass them in like so:

```
>>> a[R, C]
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Note that these can be in whatever shape you like -- the output will take the same shape:

```
>>> RR
array([0, 2, 0, 2])
>>> CC
array([0, 0, 1, 1])
>>> a[RR, CC]
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

However, if your index arrays have repetitions in them, then you can save yourself some trouble by using broadcasting. The only catch is that the resulting arrays must be broadcast*able*. That means you need to explicitly give them extra dimensions. I'll use slice syntax to preserve the extra dimension.

```
>>> r = R[0:1,:]
>>> c = C[:,0:1]
>>> r
array([[0, 2]])
>>> c
array([[0],
       [1]])
>>> a[r, c]
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

If you don't explicitly give them extra dimensions, `numpy` does its best to make sense of what you've passed, but it won't always work as expected. Replacing the `0:1` slices with `0` removes the extra dimension:

```
>>> rr = r[0,:]
>>> cc = c[:,0]
>>> rr
array([0, 2])
>>> cc
array([0, 1])
>>> a[rr, c]
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> a[r, cc]
array([[1, 4]])
>>> a[rr, cc]
array([1, 4])
```

The first one (`a[rr, c]`) works because `numpy` can tell from the shape of `c` that it should broadcast. But the other two are ambiguous, so `numpy` assumes that you don't mean them to be broadcasted.

However, note that `numpy` does also provide a shortcut for making flat arrays broadcastable. This can come in handy!

```
>>> a[numpy.ix_(rr, cc)]
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]])
```

Comment: You sure this works? I tried creating `a`, `R`, and `C` and called `a[R, C]` but it doesn't give me the result you showed.

Comment: Oh you're right. It does yield the same result. I tried a similar code a while ago and it didn't work then. I erased that code so can't debug where I went wrong... Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use slices with step=2:

```
A[1::2,1::2] = 1
```

Or explictly pass all the indexes:

```
A[[1,1,3,3],[1,3,1,3]] = 1
```

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that there's a way to implement your second example with broadcasting. `a[[[1], [3]], [[1, 3]]]`. I think that might have been what the OP was aiming for originally.

Comment: how about, a[np.ix_([1, 3], [1, 3])]?

Comment: @senderle, I ended up using broadcasting with transpose. If you wanted to put that as a separate answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> A = np.zeros(16).reshape(4,4)
>>> A[[[1],[3]], [[1, 3]]] = 1
>>> A
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.]])
```

What's happening here is that the row indices [[1],[3]] have shape (2, 1), so they can be broadcast against the column indices [[1, 3]], which have shape (1, 2), resulting in shapes (2, 2) arrays of row/column indices.  So we can think of the above as boing a short form for:

```
>>> A[[[1, 1],[3, 3]], [[1, 3], [1, 3]]] = 1
```

Which produces the same result.